# Xcode Git Bad Instructions

Tags: xcode, git, github, repository

I was attempting to connect xcode and github(complete noob at this) and followed these instructions and for some reason I couldn't get it to work.
http://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/1omi4n/setup_github_in_xcode_5/.

It requires you to go to the folder you stored your projects then start the commands.  Now whenever I make a project in that same folder the xcode option to create a local git repository on this computer is grayed out. I can create a project anywhere else in my computer and I get the option.

I just created a new folder right next to it and moved my projects there but I don't like the idea of having changed some settings and not know how to reverse them.  Tell me how to reverse them?  Or at least what it is I did with each command?

Also if anyone has a solid guide of how to connect Xcode 5 to github it would be greatly appreciated.  Most of the internet's information is on Xcode 4/4.5.  The best one I could find is what messed up my local git options.

Comment: That instruction looks very clear to me. Notice that the instruction is making git repo manually, not through Xcode.

Comment: do you know how to change that back so its not manual? @EnricoSusatyo

Comment: I really don't know what the situation is with you right now. Is your git repo set up? Is it not pushing to GitHub? Read some git basics here: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorial/git-basics

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo I know absolutely nothing about git.  All i've done is download it and set up a repository online.  I read through those tutorials and I now get what I did but I want to know how to undo it.

Comment: You don't have to undo it, you can now just set up the remote URL and commit your changes and then push your changes to Github.